# Java - org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetOutputStream write(int ch) method replaces \n with \r\n

Tags: java, telnet, apache-commons, carriage-return

I'm noticed that in org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetOutputStream in method write(int ch) \n is replaced with \r\n:

```
            case '\n':
                if (!__lastWasCR) { // convert LF to CRLF
                    __client._sendByte('\r');
                }
                __client._sendByte(ch);
                __lastWasCR = false;
                break;
```

Can you tell me why this is done?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Telnet uses CRLF for all line breaks.

Comment: http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1123/31.htm